# How can I tell where a title comes from (and progression towards it)?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I can see I already have some titles, and I can choose them from the achievements tab in the hero panel. But I am not sure where do they come from.

For example, I have the title 'traveler'. I assume I got this because I have some achievements in the explorer category, but I am not sure.

Is there any way to tell? or figure progression into a particular title, not just achievements?

Comment: The "Traveler" title comes from linking your account to GW1 and having at least 5 HoM points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to look at one of the Guild Wars 2 databases. Below is links to the achievements sections of the two I use:

- [Guildhead](http://www.guildhead.com/achievements)
- [GW2BD](http://www.gw2db.com/achievements)

There is also a titles section on the official [GW2 Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Title).

Keep in mind that given how new the game is, a lot of these will be incomplete.

Comment: +1, thanks for the links, it's nice knowing these titles. What I was hoping for, though, is some way to tell how far am I from reaching these titles. Maybe I'm too influenced by the Guild Wars 1 style, where I could easily tell, but in Guild Wars 2 I just haven't figured this out yet, and I wonder if anyone knows